# What is the process for generating and implementing .pxf certificates for local machine secure TCP connections in C#?

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp

Ok guys. I'm learning a C# TCP connection as a servers side and client side. First thing I want to understand the method of security and also encryption of data transfer between client and server. Data is a encrypted string package containing information what server is processing with database and sends back encrypted string. Encryption / Decryption uses a Key string. So my main question is SSL certifications. as example

```
using System;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Security.Authentication;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class Client
{
    private X509Certificate2 clientCertificate;

    public Client(string certificatePath, string certificatePassword)
    {
        clientCertificate = new X509Certificate2(certificatePath, certificatePassword);
    }

    public async Task ConnectToServer(string serverIpAddress)
    {
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
        await client.ConnectAsync(serverIpAddress, 1234);

        using (SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, ValidateServerCertificate))
        {
            try
            {
                await sslStream.AuthenticateAsClientAsync("serverName", new X509Certificate2Collection() { clientCertificate }, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
                Console.WriteLine("Client authenticated with server: " + sslStream.IsAuthenticated);
                Console.WriteLine("Client secured connection: " + sslStream.IsEncrypted);
                Console.WriteLine("Client mutual authentication: " + sslStream.IsMutuallyAuthenticated);

                // Use sslStream for secure communication with the server
                // Example: Sending data
                byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hello, server!");
                await sslStream.WriteAsync(data);
                
                // Close the connection
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (AuthenticationException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Client authentication failed: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private bool ValidateServerCertificate(object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        // Add your custom validation logic here
        // This example skips certificate validation for simplicity
        return true;
    }
}
```

As "certificatePath" i myst have a .pxf with password, but I cant find a good source on how to create one and make it work for test or learning purpose and make it trusted for local machine.

I found some couple sources on how to create With OpenSsl but as I can find only github openssl source-code I have no idea on how to make it work on my windows 10 machine for creating that .pxf file and password.

Comment: Read following Wiki Article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X.509

Comment: If you want a proper certificate that is going to be trusted by the client then you usually need to buy one.

Comment: Use keystore explorer (create CA cert, then use CA cert to sign server cert and client cert). Look at https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/572/0/using-keystore-explorer-to-generate-ca-root-and-end-user-ssl-certificates-for-marklogic-server

Comment: @Charlieface : All you need to do is to properly sign the certificate and shown in my link above.  You do not need to buy anything.

Comment: @jdweng You obviously need a CA, and that usually costs

Comment: Your searches will probably work better if you use the correct spelling. It's not a "pxf" file, it's a "pfx" file. "pfx" is actually an older standard that was incorporated and updated into PKCS #12. So searching for pkcs12 or p12 will probably get you better results. And technically, pfx/p12 files are *not* certificates, they are a more complex format that can hold many different kinds of key material but are typically used to hold a single private key together with an associated certificate chain. keystore explorer is a nice tool for playing around with these concepts.